# RTCView is not honouring the opacity styles in android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-webrtc

RTCView is not working with opacity style changes in Android. The RTC view not considering the added opacity (and the same opacity changes are working in case of iOS). Wrapping RTCView into a react-native View or TouchableOpacity is also not helpful. If there is any existing or alternative solutions to work RTCView with opacity please let me know. I am using react-native version "0.70.0+”.  Other views like for Text,FlatList Views etc are working fine with the opacity styles.
Thanks in advance.

```
import { RTCView } from 'react-native-webrtc';
import { View } from 'react-native';

<View style={{opacity: 0.7}} > 
<RTCView
objectFit = 'cover'
       streamURL = { this.state.userVideo }
       style = {{ opacity: 0.7, backgroundColor: 'transparent', Width:100, Height:100}}
       zOrder = { 1 } />
</View>
```